# Uploading file to Google drive using ajax and google app script creates empty file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, google-apps-script

I have an HTML form that is attempting to upload a file and save it in Google Drive. The actual data of the file is being lost along the way somewhere and I can't figure out where. I believe it's around the encoding of the file. The filename and filetype moves along just fine.

The current end result is a file saved in Google Drive with the correct name and filetype with a size of 8 bytes.

HTML

```
<form id="my-form">
  <label for="file" class="input input-file">
    <div class="button"><input type="file" name="file" id="file">Browse</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Upload PDF or Word Document">
  </label>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function UploadFile() {     

var formData = new FormData();
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
var file = fileInput.files[0];

formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('type', file.type);
formData.append('name', file.name);

$.ajax({
    url: 'GAS SCRIPT URL',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(results) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    },
    error: function(results) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
});

}
```

Google Apps Script

```
function doPost(e) {

try {
    var dropbox = "File Folder";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    var fileToProcess = e.parameters.file;
    var fileToProcessName = e.parameters.name;
    var fileToProcessType = e.parameters.type;

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(fileToProcess,fileToProcessType,fileToProcessName);

    var newFile = folder.createFile(blob);

  } catch (f) {
    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try the [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) instead.

Comment: Add newFile.saveAndClose() code after creating file.